# How to convert Dapper result QueryMultiple to Json in mvc?

Tags: c#, sql, json, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have 3 select like this. I have get all 3 select in sql convert to json.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetTest()
{
        string sql = $"SELECT 'Ahmad' AS N'Name',\n" +
        "1 AS N'Code',\n" +
        "0914 AS N'Phone' FOR JSON PATH\n" +
        "SELECT 'Alizadeh' AS N'NameFamily',\n" +
        "2 AS N'Code',\n" +
        "0915 AS N'Phone' FOR JSON PATH\n" +
        " \n" +
        " SELECT 'Seven' AS N'BookName',\n" +
        "3 AS N'Qty',\n" +
        "0916 AS N'IBS' FOR JSON PATH";
         var info = Connections.QueryMultiple(sql);
        return Ok(info);
 }
```

Result like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Ahmad",
    "Code": 1,
    "Phone": 914
  },
  {
    "NameFamily": "Alizadeh",
    "Code": 2,
    "Phone": 915
  },
  {
    "BookName": "Seven",
    "Qty": 3,
    "IBS": 916
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read all.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetTest()
{

    string sql = $"SELECT 'Ahmad' AS N'Name',\n" +
        "1 AS N'Code',\n" +
        "0914 AS N'Phone' FOR JSON PATH\n" +
        "SELECT 'Alizadeh' AS N'NameFamily',\n" +
        "2 AS N'Code',\n" +
        "0915 AS N'Phone' FOR JSON PATH\n" +
        " \n" +
        " SELECT 'Seven' AS N'BookName',\n" +
        "3 AS N'Qty',\n" +
        "0916 AS N'IBS' FOR JSON PATH";
    var info = Connections.SaleBranch.SqlConn.QueryMultiple(sql);
    var lstResult = new List<dynamic>();
    var isNext = false;
    do{
        var first2 = info.Read<dynamic>().Single();
        lstResult.Add(first2);
        isNext=info.IsConsumed;
    }
    while (!isNext);

    return Ok(lstResult);
}
```